# Is there a shorthand for std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m)?

Tags: c++, c++11

Exactly what the question states.  In C++, ideally 11, but curious about 14 and later too, is there a shorthand syntax for:

```
std::mutex someMutex;
std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg(someMutex);
```

Ideally something that infers the type of mutex to avoid the refactoring if I ever wanted to change to a `std::recursive_mutex`.

In other words, a way to do this:

```
std::mutex someMutex;
std::lock_guard lg(someMutex);
```

Or

```
auto lg = make_lock_guard(someMutex);
```

For all the type deduction powers of modern  C++, it just seems awfully redundant to go typing `std::lock_guard<std::mutex>` every time I want to make one.

Comment: Have you considered a typedef?

Comment: Who stops you from writing a template function that accepts a mutex and returns a lock guard?

Comment: Implementing `make_lock_guard` should only be a line or two of code.

Comment: @ForceBru - I tried. std::lock_guard is  not movable or copyable.

Comment: @BrianMcFarland, you could use `unique_lock` instead, which can be used as a movable lock_guard.

Comment: @BrianMcFarland That is a good point.  I forgot it was not movable.  C++17 will solve this with guaranteed copy elision but that does not help you now.

Comment: As @zneak has already said, `typedef std::lock_guard<std::mutex> LockGuard;` could it be a solution for you?

Comment: As of C++17 [class template deduction](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_deduction) will be possible, so you can avoid specifying `<std::mutex>`. Additionally, guaranteed copy elision will be implemented, as was mentioned by @NathanOliver.

Comment: In C++11, the best you're gonna do is a maco. Something like `#define LOCK(m) std::lock_guard<decltype(m)> MAKE_UNIQUE_NAME(_lock){m};`, where `MAKE_UNIQUE_NAME` is a macro that does some typical `__COUNTER__`-based name generation with a given suffix. No comment on whether or not `LOCK` is a good macro name to use, or if this is a good idea at all. :)

Comment: @Alejandro - Good to know the language designers have thought about this too.  In the mean time, I might just use unique_lock as suggested by @zneak, or just continue typing and occasionally refactoring for now.  It's not so much a problem as a mild inconvenience, compared to say, Python's `threading.Lock` and `with`.

Comment: What is the point of locking a mutex you just created, with the same scope as the mutex?

Comment: @immibis - There is no point it that. My real use case here is to have a class with a mutex as a member variable for making various public functions thread safe.

Comment: @immibis - Changing from a `std::mutex` to a `std::recursive_mutex` is the rationale for wanting `auto`.  I'll usually default to `std::mutex`, but occasionally realize after the fact it should have been recursive.  Up design might avoid the problem, but who has time for that ;-).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

For pre-C++17:

```
template<class Mutex>
std::lock_guard<Mutex> make_lock_guard(Mutex& mutex) {
    mutex.lock();
    return { mutex, std::adopt_lock };
}
```

Use as:

```
std::mutex someMutex;
auto&& lg = make_lock_guard(someMutex);
```

This takes advantage of the fact that copy-list-initialization doesn't create an additional temporary (even conceptually). The one-parameter constructor is `explicit` and can't be used for copy-list-initialization, so we lock the mutex first and then use the `std::adopt_lock` constructor.

The return value is then directly bound to `lg`, which extends its lifetime to that of the reference, once again creating no temporary (even conceptually) in the process.

Comment: Is the && unnessesary in C++17 due to it's new copy ellision rules?

Comment: @Viktor Sehr. In C++ 17, constructors will be able to infer the type of the class they are constructing. So many of these make_foo functions won't be needed.

Comment: This is awesome!  Both incredibly elegant in implementation and dead simple to use.

Answer (score 20):

In addition to what @T.C.'s answer hinted at, here's the C++17 way:

```
auto lock = std::lock_guard(someMutex);
```

You can read about the changes in this proposal: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0091r3.html

Answer (score 7):

Both current answers suggest using the auto keyword to avoid typing the type name. It's not wrong but I prefer my code to contain the typename and so use the auto keyword very sparingly. I would advocate aliasing the type:

```
using MutexLockGuard = std::lock_guard<std::mutex>;
```

Answer (score 0):

For C++17 and newer use just:

```
std::lock_guard lock(mutex)
```

As template deduction will do its job for you.